# Java; my code it only takes the first run through the while statement. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class ch3_5{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double stereoDebt = 1000, intRate = .015, monthPay = 50, totalMonths=0,interest=0,totalInterest=0,leftOverMoney=0;
    while(stereoDebt<=1000){
        if (stereoDebt>=50) {
            interest=intRate*stereoDebt;
            //System.out.println(interest);
            totalInterest+=interest;
            totalMonths+=1.00;
            //System.out.println(totalInterest);

            leftOverMoney=monthPay-interest;
            //System.out.println(leftOverMoney);
            stereoDebt=stereoDebt-leftOverMoney;
            //System.out.println(stereoDebt);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        break;
    }
    if (stereoDebt<50){
        monthPay=interest+stereoDebt;
        System.out.println(interest);
        totalInterest+=interest;
        System.out.println(totalInterest);
        totalMonths+=1.00;
        System.out.println(totalMonths);
        stereoDebt=stereoDebt-monthPay;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Your total amount of months to pay off debt is "+ totalMonths +" months." + totalInterest);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code block

Comment: Well, you seem to be breaking out of the while at the end of its first iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I removed the break statement and fixed the formatting.

```
    double stereoDebt = 1000;
    double intRate = .015;
    double monthPay = 50;
    double totalMonths=0;
    double interest=0;
    double totalInterest=0;
    double leftOverMoney=0;

    while(stereoDebt<=1000){ 

        if (stereoDebt>=50) { 
            interest=intRate*stereoDebt; 
            //System.out.println(interest); 
            totalInterest+=interest; totalMonths+=1.00; 
            //System.out.println(totalInterest);

            leftOverMoney=monthPay-interest;
            //System.out.println(leftOverMoney);
            stereoDebt=stereoDebt-leftOverMoney;
            //System.out.println(stereoDebt);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        if (stereoDebt<50){
            monthPay=interest+stereoDebt;
            System.out.println(interest);
            totalInterest+=interest;
            System.out.println(totalInterest);
            totalMonths+=1.00;
            System.out.println(totalMonths);
            stereoDebt=stereoDebt-monthPay;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Your total amount of months to pay off debt is "+ totalMonths +" months." + totalInterest);
        }
    }
```